# WPF eventtrigger pass sender

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following `EventTrigger` in `DataGrid` definition:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ColumnGeneratingCommand}"
                               CommandParameter="{???}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

What should I declare as a `CommandParameter` to pass `sender` (which should be column) to the `ColumnGeneratingCommand`? Leaving this field empty leaves the command parameter empty as well (the passed object is a `string` "None").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I declare as a `CommandParameter` to pass `sender` (which should be column) to the `ColumnGeneratingCommand`?

The implementation of `InvokeCommandAction` doesn't support passing a reference to the `sender` and if you really need this in your view model, you are doing things wrong because this breaks the MVVM pattern and what it's all about.

You need to rehink your design or create your own custom `InvokeCommandAction` class. A view model should never have any direct reference to a `UIElement`.